# Отправка и получение уведомления о новых сообщениях java

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Всем привет. Уже очень давно не могу нигде найти ответ на свой вопрос, очень много подобных ответов, но всё не то. Сделал мессенджер на java, но ни как не могу разобраться с уведомлениями, пришло мне новое сообщение, должно прийти уведомление, как например в what's app. Может кто нибудь подсказать, я не слишком опытный, учусь)

Answer (score 0):

Классическое решение PUSH-уведомлений – это Firebase Cloud Messaging. Без него сделать уведомления адекватным способом, к сожалению, не выйдет.

официальная документация на настройку приложения:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=en

статья:
https://nuancesprog.ru/p/14853/

Comment: Я уже пробовал читать оф док, не могу сообразить. Я как раз в данный момент использую firebase messaging, уведы идут, но во первых я не могу настроить определённый канал, в настройках устройства категория определяется как - другое. Во вторых не получается настроить интент, щелкая по уведомлению просто переходишь на главную, не на какие настройки реакции нет, он как то работает сам по себе. А если обновлю прогу на своем устройстве, то мне приходят уведы с другими иконками, они как из коллекции рандомно меняются. Вобщем чушь какая то получается, сколько уже мучаюсь и не могу победить